# Can I use a memory card to boot ubuntu ISO file to install it on my pc?

Tags: system-installation

I have 32GB memory card and I want to utilize it instead of an USB flash drive to boot and install ubuntu on my pc. Would you mind telling me how I can do it?

Comment: Will your BIOS boot from a memory card?

Answer (score 1):

### Running Ubuntu from Memory Card

**In Ubuntu** you can install an ISO to Memory Card or to bootable USB using **Startup Disk Creator**, from the Live DVD or using **mkusb**: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb, **MultiBootUSB** also works well: http://multibootusb.org/.

**In Windows** you can install Ubuntu to Memory Card using **Rufus**: https://rufus.ie/, **UNetbootin**: https://unetbootin.github.io/, **MultiBootUSB**: http://multibootusb.org/ and **Universal**: https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ to name a few.

You can also **Fully install Ubuntu** to Memory Card or USB the same as to internal HDD: [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step). But a Full install is not much use when installing Ubuntu.

Most computers newer than eight years old will boot Ubuntu from Memory Card.